# Can this Haskell code be compiled as written?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to compile some Haskell code from a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221235046_Affordances_as_Qualities).
The relevent textual description and listing from the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221235046_Affordances_as_Qualities) are as follows.

**Textual description**

"*We introduce AFFORDANCES as subclass of QUALITIES and exemplarily model
Climbability as a type of AFFORDANCES which inheres in a Step. The constructor of QUALITIES requires a quality like climbability to always be defined with its host. The implementation of AFFORDANCES and Climbability is shown in Listing 1. .... The class AFFORDANCES, as specified in Listing 1 provides the specification
how to write an affordance in Haskell. Climbability implements this specification.*"

**Listing 1**

```
class (QUALITIES affordance physicalEndurant, PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS physicalEndurant) => AFFORDANCES affordance physicalEndurant

data PHYSICAL_OBJECTS step => Climbability step = Climbability step

instance QUALITIES  Climbability Step
instance AFFORDANCES Climbability Step
```

As it stands **Listing 1** is missing some definitions, which I have added to the code in **Listing 2**.

**Listing 2**

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  MultiParamTypeClasses, DatatypeContexts,FlexibleInstances #-}
data Step =  Step
class  PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS physicalEndurant where
class  PHYSICAL_OBJECTS physicalEndurant where
class  QUALITIES affordance physicalEndurant where

instance  PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS (Climbability Step) where
instance  PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS Step where

class (QUALITIES affordance physicalEndurant,PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS physicalEndurant) => AFFORDANCES affordance physicalEndurant

data PHYSICAL_OBJECTS step => Climbability step = Climbability step
-- extra arguments
instance QUALITIES  (Climbability Step) Step
instance AFFORDANCES (Climbability Step) Step
```

But to get **Listing 2** to compile I had to alter **Listing 1**, by adding extra arguments to the QUALITIES and AFFORDANCES instances. Am I missing some way to get the original code from the paper to compile?

Comment: Irks that code is horrible. [Data constraints??](https://wiki.haskell.org/Data_declaration_with_constraint) Not to mention the capitalisation crimes. Anyway... could you fix the indentation, so this is actually testable?

Comment: The best way by far to handle a datatype context is to delete it.

Comment: @ leftaroundabout I am aware that data constraints are depreciated. But for research purposes I need to get my code as near to the original as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler to expect that the `affordance` parameter in classes `QUALITIES` and `AFFORDANCES` is a type constructor—in other words, has kind `* -> *` and not `*`.

If you add `{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}` to your extensions, you can then annotate `QUALITIES` with that kind signature and the rest will follow:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, DatatypeContexts, FlexibleInstances, KindSignatures #-}

data Step = Step   
class PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS physicalEndurant where   
class PHYSICAL_OBJECTS physicalEndurant where   
class QUALITIES (affordance :: * -> *) physicalEndurant where 

instance PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS Step where   


class ( QUALITIES affordance physicalEndurant
      , PHYSICAL_ENDURANTS physicalEndurant
      ) => AFFORDANCES affordance physicalEndurant

data PHYSICAL_OBJECTS step => Climbability step = Climbability step    

instance QUALITIES Climbability Step      
instance AFFORDANCES Climbability Step
```